# Mailing template not picking up images

Tags: upgrade, message-templates, images

Drupal: 7.59 CiviCRM 5.3.2
After Upgrading to 5.3.2 my mail temaplates are no longer showing the images (logo signature) I checked the path in the template and they are correct but the generated PDF shows 'image not found' 
Also I do not get a editor for the template just the raw HTML

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: some more information - I am now able to see the editor.( I had ckeditor and wysiwyg enable - I disable wsyiwyg). But when I click browse I get this  "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
You must be logged in with proper permissions to edit, add, or delete uploaded images." I am logged in as admin.  Any suggestion?

Comment: I have new information: I move the file to the same location as the image files in CKeditor and the image is now being accessed by CKEDItor. So the issues seems to be the CKEDITOR cannot access the path of the configure Image directory. As noted below - the developer tools indicate that the path is accessible. Does anyone have information on permission that CKeditor needs?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to have been caused by an automatically created .htaccess file in the Resource Image folder. This is being automatically generated but I don't know by what. The contents of the automatically generated file was 

  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all

This prevented the image file from being access. As a quick fix I renamed the file and a new file was there again in less than a minute. I edited the file to allow access and that resolved the issue. 
Though I don't understand where the htaccess file is created from, this can be marked as resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's something in your Resource URL that's off.  I would open the web browser's Developer tools (press F12) and go to the Network tab.  I expect that when you go to the template editing page, you'll see some 404 errors on the Network tab.  Compare the URLs being loaded to what the actual file location is and you may have your answer.  Don't forget to check for http:// on pages that should be https:// and vice versa.

Comment: tried that - the image url is showing with a method of GET and a Status of 200. there are no 404 errors.